# Show $(\frac{x^n}{n!})'=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $x\in\mathbb{C}$ with $x^{[n]}=\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and $x^{[-1]}=0$. Show for $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$ that $(x^{[n]})'=x^{[n-1]}$.

---

Our lecture has not introduced integrals yet, let alone the gamma function, we have only so far covered differential calculus up to the Taylor series.

I know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$, but surely the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ itself again and thus not what we're looking here for…right?  Can anybody suggest a workable approach to me? I'm quite stumped right now, even though this exercise is apparently intended to be not that hard.

Comment: Do you know that $(x^n)'=n x^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating with respect to $x$ means you keep the other constants as a variable. Therefore, ignore the $n!$ in the denominator.$$f(x)=\frac {x^n}{n!}\qquad\implies\qquad f'(x)=\frac {nx^{n-1}}{n!}$$Expand the factorial as the product of integers and simplify$$\begin{align*}f'(x) & =\frac {nx^{n-1}}{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots1}\\ & =\frac {x^{n-1}}{(n-1)(n-2)\cdots1}\\ & =\frac {x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Oh, thank you…this seems like fundamental knowledge I should have had. My apologies.

Comment: @math_mu It's okay.

Comment: This is not true for $n=0$, and that is likely the issue that the OP is facing.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{x^n}{n!}\right) &= \frac1{n!} \left[\frac{d}{dx}x^{n}\right]
\end{align}

Simplify the term in the square bracket and then use the property of factorial to get your desired answer.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating with respect to $x$ gives $$\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\frac{x^n}{n!}\Big)=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d(x^n)}{dx}=\frac{1}{n!}nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{n(n-1)(n-2)...(1)}nx^{n-1}=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$

Comment: That is not correct when $n=0$.  And that is where the issue for the OP likely lies.